# whats the current state of navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia for audio on IOS

Tags: ios, web-audio-api

I know this has been asked before but those answers are a little dated and Apple keeps changing things. I have an PWA app that runs fine on mac (safari , chrome),windows (Chrome, edge), android (chrome, edge). But does not work on ios safari or chrome

I am testing on an IPad running ios 15.4

- not sure which of navigator.mediaDevices.GetUserMedia, navigator.getUserMedia, navigator.webKitGetUSerMedia... is supposed to work
- do I need to be served from HTTPS?
- does audioWorklet work on any IOS browser (I can work without this, but prefer to use it)

Answer (score 0):

OK well I now know a lot more about this so will add my own answer. This is microphone input

AudioWorklet works on current safari on IOS but there are many oddities to be aware of

- console.log from the worklet is not reported by web inspector. So I ended up writing log messages to the worklet's messageport and logging them in the code that started the worklet
- many audio examples do a lot of juggling to try to locate the 'getUserMedia'  function. Safari will only work if is called like this

  `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

If you do

```
getUserMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMEdia || .... || .... ;
getUserMedia(....)
```

Safari will throw complaining that that function must be called a child of mediaDevices

- The size of the inputs array spontaneously changes after 100 or so samples for no apparent reason. Starts out with inputs[0][0] and inputs[0][1]. Ie stereo input left and right. After 100 or so samples it suddenly only has inputs[0][0], ie mono.
- the reporting of exceptions in the worklet in non existant, everything just silently fails.
- async await code does not try catch properly

Ie this code

```
async foo(){
      try{
          ..
          await xxx();
          ...
      catch(e){
          log(e);
      }
 }
```

does not catch an exception thrown by xxx